# Ember CLI still looks for app.css after installing broccoli-sass plugin

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli

After installing the broccoli-sass plugin in my ember-cli application with `npm install --save-dev broccoli-sass`, cli still tries to include app.css rather than look for a app.scss or app.sass file.

Is there another step necessary to get SASS working in Ember CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Just change app.css to app.scss and use that to import all the partials you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally realized I had to restart the ember server after installing the `broccoli-sass` module

I also had to change the name of the file as @Bloomfield said